# Use css sprites resource images

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

My ASP.NET MVC/ASP.NET website use image resource for globalization: Viet Nam and English. I use css to set background  or

tag without (I don't want to use this). My scenarios: I change culture(it stored in cookie), the new image resource is loaded, and I can use css to sprites that.
My solution: I think I'll use JQuery to get culture and create duplicate css class for specific image base culture. You think it's ok? It's has something wrong? or not?

I'm appreciated with your help. Thanks for reading.
Justin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better idea is to use a dynamically loaded CSS file per culture. Maybe even with a base CSS file with all culture-less styles and use seperate CSS files for the cultures when needed.

This way you only have to add a new CSS when a new Culture needs to be added. You can dynamically load the CSS from code behind in for instance the Masterpage.

You can even combine these different CSS files as 1 download for performance using something like [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you save your image name like this: icon_vn.jpg, icon_en.jpg you can try like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My project";
    var img = "icon_" + @HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["language"].Value + ".jpg";
}
<img id="hhdghasgh" src='@img' />
```